# Issue with pdfx and geometry package

Tags: geometry, pdfx

I seem to have a problem when I want to use both geometry and pdfx package together. In detail, I want to change the margins of one page, because the table is much too large. I do not want to argue, if this does look nice, it is simple the instruction of my supervisor.
I also have to use PDF-A, such that I run the pdfx package. Unfortunately, the option *pass* of the geometry package somehow disables the newgeometry later on. I tried to provide a minimum example. I am running Miktex 2.8 and TexStudio 2.12 on Windows 10.
All help is appreciated.

My Code:

```
\documentclass[bibliography=totoc, listof=totoc]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}  
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{paralist}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[page, header]{appendix}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
\titlehead{University\\ Department}
\subject{Work}
\author{ABC \\
    \vspace{0.4cm}}
\title{Estimation Techniques}
\publishers{\vspace{0.4cm} Advisors: Prof\\
    Reviewers: Prof}
\date{August 2017}
\maketitle
\begin{appendices}
\newgeometry{margin=1.4cm}
\begin{landscape}
\begingroup

\footnotesize

\newcolumntype{H}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{1.2cm}}

    \begin{longtable}{HRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR}
        \caption{Classification of the gauges in the subcatchment . It can be seen that large and extreme large events (magenta and red) are detected simultaneously for nearly all gauges.}\\
            {\textbf{Gauge-ID}} & 563290 & 562012 & 563880 & 563790 & 562031 & 562040 & 564160 & 562070 & 564201 & 564300 & 564530 & 564620 & 564400 & 564410 & 562115 \\
            {\textbf{Name of gauge}} & {\textbf{Sachsen-grund}} & {\textbf{Schön-heide 3}} & {\textbf{Markers-bach 1}} & {\textbf{Aue 1}} & {\textbf{Aue 3}} & {\textbf{Nieder-schlema}} & {\textbf{Wolfers-grün}} & {\textbf{Zwickau-Pölbitz}} &{\textbf{Nieder-mülsen 1}} & {\textbf{Nieder-lungwitz}} & {\textbf{Altchem-nitz 1}} & {\textbf{Har-thau}} & {\textbf{Chem-nitz 1}} & {\textbf{Goeritz-hain}} & {\textbf{Wechsel-burg 1}} \\
            \hline

    \end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\endgroup
\restoregeometry    
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: Snapshot of table]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Could you consider displaying this table in landscape orientation?

Comment: @Bernard: I added a picture of the broken table. As you can see, the right part is missing and the margins did not change.